# Possible Homemade RCA to Aux

Tags: audio, soldering, rca

I'm going to flat out say I'm a programmer with a soldering iron. So, if I sound like I don't know what I'm talking about; take this into account.

I was browsing stores for an RCA to Aux converter. However, they are all charging 20-30$. My question, does the red and white audio connectors pass things digitally. So, could I just solder Aux wire to Red/White wire?

Thank you,
Nate

Comment: You're going to the wrong stores. A RCA-to-3.5mm stereo jack cable shouldn't set you back more than $15, and even that is pessimistic.

Comment: What kind of connector do you need for the Aux end? What are you planning to connect with this converter (where do the RCA plugs go and where does the Aux connector go)?

Comment: I just want to use it for audio. plug from my computer audio out to my sound amp.

Comment: Red and white colors are normally for right and left channel audio (analog). Is there any info about the sound card RCA plugs, are you sure they are outputs? Do they look like the female plugs in [this image](http://www.digotv.eu/content/uploads/RCA_vads.jpg)

Comment: I want to thank you all for your support and interest. I've found a video tutorial. thanks again.

Comment: You might also look on ebay; you can find things like this cheaper there.

Comment: Heck, you can find it cheaper on Sparkfun. And they're not known for cheap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a YouTube tutorial going through step by step: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xONOLbupRV0&

Comment: Thicker than it needs to be, but not a bad job.